# Почем return не работает в php?

Tags: php, return

Почему значение переменной не возвращается из функции:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include_once("function.php");

run();

echo $a + 10;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

function.php

```
<?php
function run(){
    $a = 10;
    return $a;
}
```

Но `return` не работает, получаем ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined variable: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php on
>   line 14

Comment: `$a = run();  echo $a + 10;`

Comment: Прочитайте об __областях видимости переменных__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что после вызова функции `run()` результат никуда не записывается и пропадает. Переменная `$a` доступна только в зоне видимости функции. Вам надо присвоить результат функции `$result = run();` К другой переменной, чтобы использовать результат данной функции.

Прочтите [данную](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) статью.